# convert GIS coordinates from WGS84 (DMS) to ITM (israel) using oracle sdo_cs

Tags: oracle, coordinates, gis

I'm trying to convert gis projection from WGS84(dms) to itm (israel) using 
oracle built in packege - sdo_cs.transform

i've tried this one :

```
select t.sdo.sdo_point.x as x
 , t.sdo.sdo_point.y as y  from (select sdo_cs.transform( 
                   sdo_geometry( 2001
                               , 8192  -- Longitude / Latitude (WGS 84)  SRID
                               , SDO_POINT_TYPE(345731,320535,NULL)
                               , null
                               , null)
                         , 2039       -- Israel / Israeli TM Grid 
                        ) as sdo
    from dual
  ) t
```

but without success.
you can see a good sample of convert [here](http://twcc.fr/en/?sc=WGS84&dc=EPSG%253A2039&wgs84=35.53055555555555%252C32.79416666666666&z=2&mt=terrain#)

thanks for your help

evyatar